# SQL Statement that Updates an Oracle Database Table from an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel

I would like to write a SQL Update command that could be run once a year to update a record for every account in an Oracle Database based on external values that are received in an excel spreadsheet.

My research thus far is indicating I may be able to use a OPENROWSET command, but most references are showing this used from Excel to MS SQL Server:

```
INNER JOIN 
  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
             'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\foldername\spreadsheetname.xls;',
             'SELECT column1name, column2name, column3name, column4name
              FROM [worksheetname$]') EXT
```

Can someone verify I am on the right path or even better provide a basic example?

The basic Psuedo logic is as follows:
For every record in the Oracle USER_DEFINED table where the CODE_FIELD is equal to "CRS" AND where I have a Value on the spreadsheet with a matching account number, Update the VALUE field for that record in the Oracle USER_DEFINED table with the contents of the "Value" column in the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're requesting, but if I were you (and since this is once a year), I would create update statements in Excel using concatenation formulas.

If the first rows/columns of Excel look like this:

```
ACCT_NBR | NEW_VALUE | CONSTRUCTED_SQL_STMT
123      | Hello     | ="Update USER_DEFINED Set VALUE = '"&B2&"' Where CODE_FIELD='CRS' And Account_Num='"&A2&"';"
456      | World     | ="Update USER_DEFINED Set VALUE = '"&B3&"' Where CODE_FIELD='CRS' And Account_Num='"&A3&"';"
```

Then just run copy/paste the resulting series of update statements into SQL*Plus.  Any that don't have a match in your DB will not trigger an update, and any that do match will get updated.

Do a `commit` at the end and you're done!

Comment: Interesting option, but I am looking for something I can create a macro for and just have a non-technical expert run according to a schedule. Thanks for the suggestion though.