# Is there a way to update an oracle database by simply editing a table in excel?

Tags: database, excel, oracle, connection, refresh

I have gotten oracle database to connect to an excel spreadsheet except for 1 issue -- the excel table is not properly refreshing (i.e. a row I deleted in oracle still shows up in excel version). How is this happening? I cannot figure out how to get it to reflect the current version of the database without making a new spreadsheet and reconnecting. Even if I clear the table, My refresh data button brings back those rows that don't exist anymore

Also, I want to make a user-friendly way to add or delete rows in oracle via excel spreadsheet. So whatever I do in excel would automatically update in the oracle database. Is this even possible or am I really overreaching?

Does anyone have any ideas or tips? I'm not very technical so please dumb down any responses

Comment: please tell me this is not for an enterprise application.  Excel is not normally thought of as a front end for an Oracle database.

Comment: An Excel Macro using VB and OleDB comes to mind...

Comment: Do a search, this has been asked before. Ideally you'd need to do some VBA code to do an update as @tbone suggested, but you may also want to look into something like this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814098/update-existing-database-values-from-spreadsheet

Comment: This can be done in Excel via use of VBA.  But please listen to @kevinsky... don't build an excel sheet as a front-end for users to be manipulating data in an oracle database.  If ultimately that is all you need to do, you might as well just go download Oracle SQL Developer which is free and it can do all that stuff for you.  Regarding your button, if you post your code others can help you on why it's not refreshing data.  For updating data your best bet is to just google around.