# Is this possible to manipulate oracle database from excel worksheet

Tags: excel, oracle

I dont want export/import. Is there any possible way to insert/update/delete  to a oracle database from microsoft excel sheet.?

Comment: Apparently, yes - see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814098/update-existing-database-values-from-spreadsheet. But you probably don't really want to do that, Excel isn't a tool which should be used to manipulate data in an Oracle database.

Comment: you could do that please check the following link https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/2062790 , but nowadays you could use scripting language like Python to load a excel file.

Comment: I checked these link, these source are pretty but I don't want to do things on that way. I want to create an automation that if I save an excel sheet the data will be saved in the database or if I delete record, data will be delete from database. Please Do not suggest me external table. Suggest me any tools that can handle the task.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (for a one-off activity) is to craft your `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` methods by concatenating strings (taking care to escape characters appropriately):

If you have the data:

```
     A   B       C      D          E
1    42  O'Brien Shamus 2020-11-25 <blank>
2    13  Adams   Alice  2020-10-30 <blank>
```

Then in cell `E1` you can put the code:

```
="INSERT INTO your_table ( id, last_name, first_name, activity_date ) VALUES ( "&A1&", '"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,"'","''")&"', '"&SUBSTITUTE(C1,"'","''")&"', DATE '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' );"
```

And then copy, paste down all the necessary `E` column cells.

Then copy/paste the DML statements you have just generated into an Oracle session and run them and you will insert the values (and then `COMMIT` the data).

You could also set up a VBA macro to do this too.

Comment: Actually I know this way. But I need to transfer data directly from excel to oracle database. Let me know is there any other possible way you have in your mind!